# How to focus next textarea on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do something like a social network, but I'm having problems with jquery, I want, by clicking the comment button, the user is taken to the comment field, but I'm not able to use `$(this)`.

When the user click here

[image]

The code:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default abreComentarios" >
   <span  class="fa fa-comments-o"></span>
 </button>
```

The field:
[image]

The code:

```
<div class="comentar">
    <textarea class="txtComentario form-control caixaComentario" placeholder="Seu comentário" onkeypress="comentarEnter()"></textarea>
</div>
```

My jquery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.abreComentarios', function() {
      //console.log('entrou');
    $(this).next('.caixaComentario').focus();
 });
```

Remember, I'm using a foreach, so I have to use `$(this)`

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your console?

Comment: @VitorZF there isn't a foreach in your provided code...

Comment: no errors, just the message that I put to know if is entering the function https://i.imgur.com/ARUem12.png

Comment: @cmprogram if I put the entire code that repeats there will be 2 pages of this question

Comment: @cmprogram take a look https://i.imgur.com/MmK6079.png

Comment: Please post RELEVANT code in a [mcve] - not a picture of code that I cannot even zoom in enough to read

Comment: If all you are trying to do is focus on the textarea, why not just use a label?  If you need to use a button, then don't forget to prevent the default action (as well as fixing that `next()`), otherwise you will submit the form and reload the page

Comment: HERE @mplungjan https://docs.google.com/document/d/163tGfNIaHIZowur12hb86-pOiAbtbBa05Sqy_fs4LtY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @cmprogram here too https://docs.google.com/document/d/163tGfNIaHIZowur12hb86-pOiAbtbBa05Sqy_fs4LtY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Next time just post the 10 RELEVANT lines of RENDERED html and the jQuery

Comment: ok :) it's my first post on stackoverflow, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i just did it:

1- Added a data-id with the id of the post in the button

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default abreComentarios" data-id="'.$post->id.'"><span class="fa fa-comments-o"></span></button>`

2- Added the same id in the end of the name of class "caixaComentario"

`<div class="comentar">
<textarea class="form-control caixaComentario'.$post->id.'" placeholder="Seu comentário" onkeypress="comentarEnter()"></textarea>
</div>`

3- Call without $(this) on jQuery

`$('body').on('click', '.abreComentarios', function() {
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   $('.caixaComentario'+id).focus();
});`

and Worked :D

Answer (score 2):

Your `next()` isn't `.caixaComentario` but `.comentar`,

So use the `next()` but then you'll have to use `find()` (or `children()`) to focus the textarea

```js
$('.abreComentarios').on('click', function() {
  //console.log('entrou');
  $(this).next('.comentar').find('.caixaComentario').focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default abreComentarios">click</button>

<div class="comentar">
  <textarea class="txtComentario form-control caixaComentario" placeholder="Seu comentário"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: or maybe `.closest()`

Comment: nop, `closest()` goes up not down: `Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.`

Comment: it works in the fiddle, instead of posting code as image or in the google drive , you need to post the relevant code in your question, but the generated html , not the PHP code

Answer (score 0):

$(this) will be your `<button>`, but calling .next(".caixaComentario") will look for a sibling element to the button. If your `<button>` and `<div class="comentar">` are siblings, the .next(".caixaComentario") will not match any elements as they aren't siblings. The  would be a niece/nephew.

Try changing .next(".caixaComentario") to .next("div .caixaComentario")